# packer is hanging here "vmware-iso: waiting for ssh to become available"

Tags: ssh, vmware, packer

I am trying to create machine image on VMware using `packer`.

While building it keeps on waiting for ssh to become available. This is my json:

```
{
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "vmware-iso",
            "boot_command": [
                "<esc><esc><enter><wait>",
                "/install/vmlinuz noapic preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg ",
                "debian-installer=en_US auto locale=en_US kbd-chooser/method=us ",
                "hostname={{ .Name }} ",
                "fb=false debconf/frontend=noninteractive ",
                "keyboard-configuration/modelcode=SKIP keyboard-configuration/layout=USA keyboard-configuration/variant=USA console-setup/ask_detect=false ",
                "initrd=/install/initrd.gz -- <enter>"
            ],
            "boot_wait": "10s",
            "disk_size": 40960,
            "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu-64",
            "http_directory": "http",
            "iso_url": "http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-server-i386.iso",
            "iso_checksum": "1214cd22448338b60bb24f583dd8741a",
            "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
            "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
            "ssh_password": "root123",
            "remote_datastore": "aaa",
            "vm_name": "aaa",
            "format": "vmx",
            "ssh_pty": "true",
            "ssh_port": "22",
            "headless": false,
            "remote_type": "esx5",
            "remote_host": "aaa",
            "remote_username": "aaa",
            "remote_password": "aaa",
            "remote_port": "22",
            "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
            "shutdown_command": "shutdown -P now"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any problems with this setup?

this is my preceed.cfg:

d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false

d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us

d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname

d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain

d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true

d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note

d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually

d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 172.22.1.74

d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.252.0

d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 172.22.64.1

d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 172.22.64.1

d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true

d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server

d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true

d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

d-i time/zone string US/Pacific

d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

d-i mirror/country string US

d-i mirror/http/proxy string

d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false

tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-server

d-i partman-auto/method string regular

d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true

d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true

d-i partman/choose_partition select finish

d-i partman/confirm boolean true

d-i passwd/user-fullname string Ubuntu User

d-i passwd/username string ubuntu

d-i passwd/user-password password root123

d-i passwd/user-password-again password root123

d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true

d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

Comment: Provide your `preseed.cfg`.

Comment: You specify `"guest_os_type": "Ubuntu-64"` but then you use an i386 ISO, that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Do i need to change anything in my precced.cfg?

Comment: #d-i passwd/root-password password root123
#d-i passwd/root-password-again password root123

Comment: d-i passwd/root-login boolean false 

should i make this true?

Comment: It needs to be correct, set the root pwd _and_ allow root to ssh with password.

Comment: Thankyou Rickard. I have changed it to Ubuntu-32. and i have made  
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true   this change in preceed.cfg . I'll try this.

Comment: Hey Rickard, can you look into my preceed.cfg and suggest if anything is wrong in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First A: You need to open your firewall for VNC.

Second A: You either need to configure a dhcp server or you have to use a static IP address which needs to be configured both in the preseed.cfg and in the packer template with  *ssh_host*.

Comment: Hey , again it is waiting for ssh to become available. 

i made headless=false , but GUI is not opening.

Comment: Where do you expect the GUI to open? You are running on a remote ESXi. Try to open a console in vSphere or use the ESXi Embedded Host Client.

Comment: i tried running json file with this command
PACKER_LOG=1 packer build test1.json

this is the output-

"waiting for ssh to become available" -

"opening new ssh session"

"starting remote command: esxcli --formatter csv network vm list"
 

" [DEBUG] Error getting SSH address: EOF"

"Timeout waiting for ssh"

Comment: Which console you meant?

Comment: The console that emulates a screen and keyboard. https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VMRC1001&productId=614

Comment: I opened console in Vsphere client. Here it is stopping.

Network autoconfiguration failed 

Your network is not using the DHCP protocol. Alternatively the DHCP server may be slow or some network hardware is not working properly.

Comment: i am also getting this error.
Failed to retrieve  preconfiguration file.
The file needed for preconfiguration could not be retrieved from http://172.22.6.1:8335/preseed.cfg.

Comment: i have added this vmx data and ssh_host in json. now build log shows this  [DEBUG] Error getting SSH address: No interface on the VM has an IP address ready. am i missing any data to add in vmx_data?


"ssh_host" :"172.22.1.74",
"vmx_data":{
"memsize": "4096",
"numvcpus": "1",
"ethernet0.present" :"true",
 "ethernet0.addressType": "generated",
"ethernet0.virtualDev" : "e1000",
"ethernet0.networkName" : "VM Network",
"ethernet0.pciSlotNumber" : "32",
"ethernet0.startConnected":"true"
},

Comment: Your preseed.cfg doesn't set the IP address. It also has to do that.

Comment: Hey Rickard, thanks for helping . Now its connected to ssh, but stuck at 
" vmware-iso : Gracefully halting Virtual Machine" . is it because of shutdown command?

Comment: Most likely. You have to sudo to shutdown.

Comment: Thankyou Rickard. Build is successfully done. How to start the VM using terraform? should i add vpshere post processor in packer template to do so?